# Replicating results from pd.merge in SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, select

I've been playing around with some datasets locally in Python, and am now trying to replicate the same results in a cloud environment with SQL.

I have 3 tables, each with multiple duplicate IDs. For example, table A will contain IDs `a, b, c, d, ...`, table B will contain IDs `a, c, e, a1, a2 ...`, and table C will contain IDs `d, f, a2, b1, b2, ...`

I am currently doing `pd.merge` for table A and table B on ID `a`, and table C with the resulting table from the first merge on ID `a2`. On using pd.merge, I noticed that it would add a `_x` or a `_y` to the duplicate IDs (by that, I mean in the first `pd.merge` of table A and table B, `c` from table A would become `c_x`, and `c` from table B would become `c_y` and so on for any other duplicate IDs. The same would apply to any other duplicate IDs for any joins.

How would I be able to replicate this process and bypass the issue with duplicate IDs in SQL?

Comment: can you post some codes to show how you are now merging the data and how you would like the result to be? It's not clear how you'd like to deal with the duplicated rows and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple join and alias Value:

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': list('abcde'),'Value': [1,2,3,4,4] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ' a b e a1 a2'.split(),'Value': [10,20,30,40,40] })
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': 'd f a b b2'.split(),'Value': [100,200,300,400,400] })

# Merge using pandas
df = df1.merge(df2,on='ID').merge(df3,on='ID')
print('using pd.merge')
print(df)

# Using SQL
con = sqlite3.connect("mydb.db")
df1.to_sql("df1", con, if_exists='replace',index=False)
df2.to_sql("df2", con, if_exists='replace',index=False)
df3.to_sql("df3", con, if_exists='replace',index=False)

# sql query
q = """
select df1.Value as Value_df1, df2.Value as Value_df2, df3.Value as Value_df3
from df1
join df2
on df1.ID = df2.ID
join df3
on df1.ID = df3.ID
"""
out = pd.read_sql_query(q,con)
print()
print('-'*50)
print('using sql')
print(out)
con.close()
```

## outputs

```
using pd.merge
  ID  Value_x  Value_y  Value
0  a        1       10    300
1  b        2       20    400

--------------------------------------------------
using sql
   Value_df1  Value_df2  Value_df3
0          1         10        300
1          2         20        400
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rename in the join the rest of the joined columns with new names:

```
SELECT table_A.ID_a, table_A.c_ID as c_ID_from_A, table_B.c_ID as c_ID_from_B
FROM table_A
JOIN table_B ON(table_A.ID_a = table_B.ID_a)
```

Hope you find it usefull.